# Dynamically opening an array of jquery accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, accordion

So I'm trying to iterate through a class of accordion jquery objects, check which ones are open, add those to an array, then (after a reset of the accordions) reopen the accordions which were open before. This seems like a really simple question, and I apologize, but in my searches it seems like the questions were just about iterating using jquery generally, not about iterating over arrays of jquery objects. I just couldn't find an answer really.

This is what I currently have, which for some reason isn't working. First, the array of already open accordions is created.

```
        $(".accordionClass").each(
            function(){
                if($(this).accordion("option", "active") !== false) {
                    activeArray.push($(this));
                }
            }
        );
```

This seems to work. At least, activeArray.length gives the correct number of objects.

Then, I try to open all of the accordions in this array later, after they've been reinitialized.

```
    $.each(activeArray,
        function(){
            $(this).accordion({ active: 0 });
        }
    );
```

And no dice. They don't open. Any ideas?

Comment: as active array already contains jquery object.. you can do this.accordian({active:0}). but better solutions would to, as suggested, to save the DOM object into array instead of jQuery object. Hope you are not  re-creating DOM objects?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to Question**

In the question as written, you are pushing jQuery objects (`$(this)`) into your array, reading them out, and then wrapping the objects in another jQuery selector.

You should instead just push the native DOM object, `this`.

---

**Solution to Problem**

The specific problem here (found in the comments on this answer, and not the question itself) is that the object is being destroyed, and then a similar object is being created (from the same markup). This is generally bad practice, but it also leads to the problem in the question: The object referred to by the `this` pushed into the array no longer exists by the time it is read out.

Instead, you should push `this.id`, and then use jQuery to reselect the copy with `$('#'+this)`.

Comment: Still nothing. I've also tried a couple other ways of opening, such as 
    `$(this).accordion("option","active",0);`
with no result, so I'm really not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry I can't help more; I'm afk. Try investigating the object contents with JSON.stringify. And try getting all of the accordions to open (or just one specific one) to find the correct way to open them.

Comment: Hmm yeeeah. So `JSON.stringify(activeArray);` gives `[{},{},{}]` when done on an array that was populated using only `this`. When instead populated with `$(this)`, stringify gives `[{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1}]`. I must confess, I don't know enough about JSON or jquery to know if these are as expected, or completely broken. Meanwhile, getting all accordions to open was quite easy, using `$(".accordionClass").each(
   function(){
    $(this).accordion({ active: 0 });
   }
  );` So it seems the problem lies in the array..

Comment: @king_cole If you can make a fiddle of your problem, I can figure out what's wrong. Here is an example of a working fiddle, but I clearly use different accordion code: https://jsfiddle.net/ube5jq7w/.

Comment: Here's what I've come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/L5h6v358/ The actual script creates the interior accordions (the big html string) dynamically by sending input to exterior scripts and then calling the main functions as response functions from the post calls, but I've tried to maintain the actual structure as much as possible. For some reason, the on click function doesn't seem to work on this fiddle and I can't seem to figure that out, so I'm sorry that I'm showing you crap that doesn't even work properly. I suck.

Comment: Just in case you didn't actually see this because I didn't use the @ thing, I don't really know how this works haha. If you saw and just didn't answer that's completely fine, just seemed silly if you'd not even seen it because I messed up haha. @Kittsil

Comment: @king_cole Your problem was that the onclick function was not in scope; I handled this using jQuery's `$.click()` function. It seems to be working, otherwise... http://jsfiddle.net/L5h6v358/1

Comment: Ah, thank you! But, does it seem to be working otherwise? For me at least, if I open the main accordion (with the "Reset x times" heading), then the Type 1 accordion, then the Prerequisite accordion, then I click reset, the prior two will reopen, and the Prerequisite one will not - which is the problem I'm trying to solve. The former two are not generated dynamically and exist as single accordions, and their reopening is mediated through a different mechanism. But the problem relates to the third level, the Prerequisite accordion, which seems to still not open. Thanks for your time. @Kittsil

Comment: @king_cole Congratulations! You stumped me for an entire half hour (in addition to the days since you asked the question). However, the cause of your problem is obvious: The object you put in the array has been destroyed. If you're going to destroy and recreate the object, you should save it's id, and not the object itself. http://jsfiddle.net/L5h6v358/5/ (I added a timeout so that you can observe it working.)